# Chart.js Radar Chart How to Remove Outer Labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js, axis-labels, radar-chart

[image]

On mobile, these labels are taking up too much valuable space. How can I remove them while keeping the lines?

I've tried several methods, ones that seem to work for typical x/y graphs, but can't find a way to achieve this for the radar chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution! see below:

```
options: {
    scale: {
        pointLabels: {
            callback: function(pointLabel, index, labels) {
                return screen_w > 500 ? pointLabel : ' ';
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a variable of my own `screen_w` to conditionally return the label, or nothing.

Works like a charm.

Found buried here:
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/1879

Comment: what suppose is the screen_w or what's the value?

Comment: an integer - I believe in this case via window.innerWidth, but it's been quite awhile.

Answer (score 3):

Found simplest solution for remove outer label for all cases

```
 scale:{
           pointLabels:{
           fontSize: 0       
             },
       }
```

Just make FontSize equal to zero